# Refreshing page after using history.replaceState() Not scrolling to the top of page

Tags: javascript, browser-history

I've implemented history.replaceState() to my site when clicking to load more. Each time you click, the script adds extra elements to the container using an ajax call and then uses replaceState. Everything is working as expected on that front, but when you click to load more a few times, and then click to refresh the page, or cmd+r, the page is refreshed, but then jumps to the bottom of the browser. My thought is that it's because it's trying to keep the same scroll position (maybe because the browser thinks it's on the same page? I dunnno, but since the page was refreshed a lot of the inserted elements are removed, so it just goes to the bottom.

Adding an anchor tag seems to work for firefox on mac, but safari is still jumping to the bottom, as is mobile safari.

Comment: Does `window.onload = function () {document.documentElement.scrollTop = 0;};` do anything?

Comment: Safari is the odd one out in that it still fires a popstate on page load, unlike other modern browsers. This could be part of the problem.

Comment: You could always add a gratuitous # to the end of the URL.  This works with many browser versions.

Comment: the window.onload function doesn't seem to work, it's being called because I'll get a console.log, but it's not doing it, neither is using $(document).ready().

Comment: And I've tried adding a # at the end, originally having something that wasn't a real anchor tag, and again using a real anchor tag and it doesn't seem to be going to it. I mean I could probably set a timeout to jump to the top, but it'd be jumpy, and I'd just have to hope the timing worked out, so I'd rather a cleaner way.

Comment: To clarify, when using the $(document).ready() function the console.log statement is fired, but then it jumps to the bottom right after that. So it's like it's scrolling to the top (or not really because it's already there) but then jumping to the bottom right after.